# Set up hidden button on UIwebview page

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uibutton, nsdata

1.I am working on `UIWebView` and I wanna to ask how do set up hidden button on the `UIWebView` or navigation bar (with buttons on) I want to implement tap screen to show those buttons.
Can anyone give me some suggestions?

2.I am using http get to get image from such address:10.103.198.246:85/snapshot.cgi (api only support get method)
how do I display that image using returning data?

```
NSURL *url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://@10.103.198.246:85/snapshot.cgi"];
              NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url1 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
              NSData *received = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:received encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

This how I get text info. but how do i display image data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a Tap gesture recognizer to the UIWebView. On the tap event, add a semi-transparent view to the WebView and add the buttons you need to that new view.
2. UIImage has an -initWithData: method that you can use to get the UIImage object. Not sure in a .cgi extension is supported, might only by common formats like .jpg or .png

   UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:received.....];